# Azure.Storage.Blobs returns different list from WindowsAzure.Storage on creation

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have this test code which connects to Azure Blob Storage in two ways with the same credentials, once with the now deprecated `WindowsAzure.Storage` package and once the new `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package:

```cs
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Linq;

namespace EntityFrameworkTest
{
    public class AzureBlobStorageTests
    {

        [Test]
        public void TestStorage()
        {
            string storageAccount = "MyConnectionString";
            string containerName = "testazureblobobjectstore";

            var clientNew = new BlobServiceClient(storageAccount);
            var containerNew = clientNew.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            containerNew.CreateIfNotExists();
            var blobsListNew = containerNew.GetBlobs();

            var accountOld = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount);
            var clientOld = accountOld.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var containerOld = clientOld.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            containerOld.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            BlobContinuationToken config = new BlobContinuationToken();
            var blobsListOld = containerOld.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(config).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Results;
            
            Assert.AreEqual(blobsListOld.Count(), blobsListNew.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

The lengths of the two lists differ:

In `blobsListOld` I have 2 items:

1. The directory
2. A `BlockBlob` with name `__id__foo`.

In `blobsListNew` I have 3 items, all are `BlockBlob`s with the following names:

1. `` //||!@#$%^&*()_-=+[]'<>~;:`? ``
2. `` /||!@#$%^&*()_-=+[]'<>~;:`? ``
3. `__id__foo`.

Can anyone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 0):

I tried in my system to test  the both return count of blobs  which connects to Azure Blob Storage using deprecated `WindowsAzure.Storage` package and once the new `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package:  Both returning the same value .

Try with this code

```
            string storageAccount = "Connection String";
            string containerName = "test";

            var clientNew = new BlobServiceClient(storageAccount);
            var containerNew = clientNew.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            containerNew.CreateIfNotExists();
            
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = clientNew.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
            // List all blobs in the container using new 
            await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
            }

            var accountOld = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount);
          
            CloudBlobClient clientOld = accountOld.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            
            CloudBlobContainer container = clientOld.GetContainerReference("test");
           //List all blobs using old 

            CloudBlobDirectory dira = container.GetDirectoryReference(string.Empty);
            
            var rootDirFolders = dira.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(true, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, null, null, null, null).Result;

            foreach (var blob in rootDirFolders.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( blob.Uri);
            }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I see you've changed the way the old parts work, while I want to understand how to change the new code so it works more or less the same, so I expect to see the `__id__foo` block blob and have it as the only block blob.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the `__id__foo` is it container  or blob name ? and what actually you want to know

Comment: it's supposed to be the only Block Blob, except it's not the way it is when I run with the new package.

Comment: Ya , Have you tried above answer code? How your folder structure  looks like in azure storage?

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I had to use `containerNew.GetBlobsByHierarchy(delimiter: "/");` to get only the blobs in the root folder.